# Docker compose with vaultwarden and NGINX bad gateway error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm running docker compose with nginx and vaultwarden (and certbot) image but I always get this error:

2023/04/18 11:42:27 [error] 20#20: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: bw.domain.tld, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host: "bw.domain.tld", referrer: "https://bw.domain.tld/"
2023/04/18 11:42:31 [error] 20#20: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: bw.domain.tld, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "bw.domain.tld"

This is the output of ss -tulpn | grep LISTEN

```
tcp LISTEN 0 4096 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:*
tcp LISTEN 0 4096 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:*
tcp LISTEN 0 4096 127.0.0.53%lo:53 0.0.0.0:*
tcp LISTEN 0 128 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:*
tcp LISTEN 0 4096 0.0.0.0:443 0.0.0.0:*
tcp LISTEN 0 4096 [::]:80 [::]:*
tcp LISTEN 0 4096 [::]:8080 [::]:*
tcp LISTEN 0 128 [::]:22 [::]:*
tcp LISTEN 0 4096 [::]:443 [::]:*
```

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
bitwarden:
image: vaultwarden/server:latest
container_name: vaultwarden
ports:
- 8080:80
volumes:
- ./vaultwarden/vw-data/:/data
restart: always
environment:
- WEBSOCKET_ENABLED=true
- SIGNUPS_ALLOWED=true
- SIGNUPS_VERIFY=FALSE
- INVITATIONS_ALLOWED=FALSE
- SHOW_PASSWORD_HINT=FALSE
- ADMIN_TOKEN='my-admin-token'
- DOMAIN=https://bw.domain.tld

nginx:
image: nginx:latest
container_name: nginx
ports:
- 80:80
- 443:443
restart: always
volumes:
- ./nginx/conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
- ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:ro
- ./certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:ro
certbot:
image: certbot/certbot:latest
container_name: certbot
volumes:
- ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:rw
- ./certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw
```

and this is NGINX default.conf

```
# The `upstream` directives ensure that you have a http/1.1 connection
# This enables the keepalive option and better performance
#
# Define the server IP and ports here.
upstream vaultwarden-default {
  zone vaultwarden-default 64k;
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
  keepalive 2;
}
upstream vaultwarden-ws {
  zone vaultwarden-ws 64k;
  server 127.0.0.1:3012;
  keepalive 2;
}

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name bw.domain.tld;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name bw.domain.tld;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bw.domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bw.domain.tld/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bw.domain.tld/fullchain.pem;

    client_max_body_size 128M;

      location / {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header "Connection" "";

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass http://vaultwarden-default;
    }

    location /notifications/hub/negotiate {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header "Connection" "";

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass http://vaultwarden-default;
    }

    location /notifications/hub {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Forwarded $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass http://vaultwarden-ws;
    }
}
```

Any idea?
Thank you in advance,
Marco

Comment: `server 127.0.0.1:8080;`  if you're running in different containers, this shouldn't be 127.0.0.1.    It should be `bitwarden` since that's the service name you defined.

Comment: @eirk258 thanks for your tip. I also had to delete port mapping in docker-compose.yml  for bitwarden service and now it works!